# My snake program won't show the objects I drew. How can I fix it?

Tags: c#

I'm following a snake tutorial right now and I wrote the exact thing as said, but it won't even show the rectangles of the snake and food.`enter code here`
I'm using Windows Form Application.
I made separate classes - Food; Snake; And the one for the form.

```
//Snake class
public Rectangle[] Body;
        private int x = 0, y = 0, width = 20, height = 20;

        public Snake()
        {
            Body = new Rectangle[1];
            Body[0] = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        }
        public void Draw()
        {
            for (int i = Body.Length - 1; i < 0; i--)
                Body[i] = Body[i - 1];
        }

        public void Draw (Graphics graphics)
        {
            graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.AliceBlue, Body);

        }

         public void Move (int direction)         
         {
            Draw();

//Food Class
public class Food
    {
        public Rectangle Piece;
        private int x, y, width = 20, height = 20;

        public Food(Random rand)
        {
            Generate(rand);
            Piece = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        }

        public void Draw(Graphics graphics)
        {
            Piece.X = x;
            Piece.Y = y;
            graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, Piece);
```

Comment: Where does the Graphics parameter come from?

Answer (score 0):

You are not inheriting your body and food classes from any form of drawable context objects.  So the "draw" routine would need to be explicitly called any time a change happens.  You appear to be trying to mimic the structure of a WinForms UI component, where it has its own built-in Draw() method that is implicitly called any time the UI needs to update.

Also, since you are calling "Draw" without any parameters, that should be throwing an error unless you have an overload somewhere that doesn't require parameters. In which case, there would be no graphics context to draw to.

I'm no expert in doing game graphics, but I do know that constantly calling the redraw method of a UI component is exceptionally inefficient.  There are overrides for the Invalidate() method where you can provide rectangles to invalidate only small portions of the entire component.  That can help with improving redraw rate.

I would suggest having a single renderable UI component on screen that links to your data objects.  And override the draw() method of that component so that it draws the entire game board (or portions of it based on the invalidated regions), based on the data stored in your game objects.